# Can the crypto module replace bcryptjs and jsonwebtoken, and would you recommend it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jwt, bcrypt

I know that the crypto module is fairly new but from what I've seen it's quite powerful and could do what these two packages are able to. Can't this module just replace these two packages or am I missing something here?

Comment: no, crypto module doesn't implement JWT, what code you don't use by not using a package you would need to write to replace it. Having oxygen and hydrogen doesn't magically make water

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to only use the ceypto module, but it provides a low-level API. To properly sign, verify, encrypt or decrypt JWTs, you would need to implement methods which will use the crypto API. Using libraries is just simpler, and if you use popular libraries you have more certainty that they implemented the standards in the right way. When choosing a library for handling JWTs it's best to try to find one with minimal dependencies, as they should, as you noticed, mainly use the crypto module.